# How to check if the value type is compatible with the function expected type?

Tags: php

I am about to do some heavy refactoring in a legacy project and want to start using string types in our Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) as a part of refactoring. But before doing this, I want to find all the usages of our DTOs that will fail should we do this as right now there are a lot of invalid usages like this

```
/**
 * @param null|int $value
 */
public function intValueSetter($value) {
    // do something
}

$dto->intValueSetter(['value' => 1]);
```

I have already implemented a function that accepts the method expected type from the phpDoc and the actual value passed. I also managed to implement strict validation where based on the type I will check value by appropriate functions like `is_bool`, `is_string`, etc.

```
function assertValueType(mixed $value, string $expectedTypes): bool
{
    $valueTypes = explode('|', $expectedTypes);

    foreach ($valueTypes as $valueType) {
        $assertFunction = $this->getAssertFunction($valueType);

        if (!$assertFunction($value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is, this is a strict validation. I also want to have another, more loose function that checks whether the actual exception will be raised should the value be passed in the method once it has strict types.

For example,

```
public function intValueSetter(int $value): void
{
    // do something
}

// will work (even though it's incorrect and still has to be fixed)
$dto->intValueSetter('1');
$dto->intValueSetter(false);
$dto->intValueSetter(11.11);

// exception
$dto->intValueSetter([]);
$dto->intValueSetter('string here');
```

However, I'm having a hard time coming up with an idea of how to do this. I would appreciate any suggestion or example on how to achieve what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your function, like:

```
/**
 * @param null|int $value
 */
public function intValueSetter($value) {
    if (($value !== null) && ($value !== intval($value))) {
        //throw an exception and/or log something
    }
    // do something
}
```

you could do this in an experimental branch as well, to avoid your users encountering such issues, but you do not necessarily need to throw an error. This kind of logging, especially if you log the stack trace will make sure that you find the references that are actually used and therefore more urgent to tackle than the others.